# GetLastInputInfo does not detect touchpad scrolling

Tags: windows, winapi, touchpad

I am trying to find CPU idle time using GetLastInputInfo(). This works for all keyboard buttons and mouse/touchpad movement and clicks. While this also detects external mouse's scrolling, it fails to detect two finger scrolling on laptop touchpad!!

Any solutions?

Comment: What OS exhibits this behavior? Up to and including Windows 7 you will see all sorts of inexplicable behavior with respect to touch input. And while a driver issue cannot be excluded, what laptop model and what driver have you used to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: I am using Win10 on Lenovo L440. It uses synaptic touch pad driver.

Comment: In that case it sounds like the driver swallows the input, and simply sends a [WM_VSCROLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787577.aspx) message to the window under the current cursor position. Instead, it should synthesize input calling [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx), with the equivalent of a mouse wheel input. You probably have to talk to the driver vendor.

Comment: Yes. It is swallowed by the synaptic driver. I could not find any simpler solution to fix it.